# Lilypond – how can I write lyrics to rests in multiple stanzas?

Tags: lilypond, lyrics

could someone help me with my problem, please?

I have got this Lilypond 2.18.2 code:

```
\version "2.18.2"
\language "deutsch"

global = {
  \time 4/4
  \set Timing.beamExceptions = #'()
  \set Timing.baseMoment = #(ly:make-moment 1/8)
  \set Timing.beatStructure = #'(2 2 1 1 2)
}

melody = \relative c' {
  \global
   r4 r r8 d d d
}

accRight = \relative c' {
  \global
  r8 <h d g> <h d g> <h d g> <h d g> r r4

}

accLeft = \relative c {
  \global
  g4 g' g, g'
}

verseOne = \lyricmode {
  a a a  
}

verseTwo = \lyricmode {
  b b b 
}
choirOne = \lyricmode {
  (a a a a)
}
choirTwo = \lyricmode {
  (b b b b)
}


\score {
  <<
    \new ChoirStaff <<
      \new Staff <<
        \new Voice { \voiceOne \melody }
        \addlyrics { \verseOne }
        \addlyrics { \verseTwo }
        \new Voice { \voiceTwo \accRight }
        \addlyrics { \choirOne }
        \addlyrics { \choirTwo }
      >>
      \new Staff { \clef bass \accLeft }
    >>
  >>
}
```

It looks like this:

[image: excerpt]

And now I want to have all a's in lyrics in the first line and all b's in the second line, but do nothing with notes. Like this (done with Windows Paint):

[image: goal]

Somehow put the lyrics on the rests, but keep the rests here. I have already tried multiple solution, but none of them have worked with multiple stanzas. Could you help me, please? I do not need midi, only the sheet.

Comment: @VitHenych I propose an even better solution using `NullVoice`, see the answer. Also note that `q` is a short-cut for the last chord entered using the `<...>` notation, so `<h d g> q d q` is the same as `<h d g> <h d g> d <h d g>`. It eases the coding :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine two voices into a single `NullVoice` and then add lyrics to this:

```
\version "2.18.2"
\language "deutsch"

global = {
  \time 4/4
  \set Timing.beamExceptions = #'()
  \set Timing.baseMoment = #(ly:make-moment 1/8)
  \set Timing.beatStructure = #'(2 2 1 1 2)
}

melody = \relative d' {
  \global
   r4 r r8 d d d
}

accRight = \relative h {
  \global
  r8 <h d g> q q q r r4
}

accLeft = \relative g, {
  \global
  g4 g' g, g'
}

%verseOne = \lyricmode { a a a }
%verseTwo = \lyricmode { b b b }
%choirOne = \lyricmode { (a a a a) }
%choirTwo = \lyricmode { (b b b b) }
alltextOne = \lyricmode { (a a a a) a a a }
alltextTwo = \lyricmode { (b b b b) b b b }

\score {
  <<
    \new ChoirStaff <<
      \new Staff <<
        \new Voice { \voiceOne \melody }
        \new Voice { \voiceTwo \accRight }
        \new NullVoice = "allvoice" << \melody \accRight >>
      >>
      \new Lyrics \lyricsto "allvoice" { \alltextOne }
      \new Lyrics \lyricsto "allvoice" { \alltextTwo }
      \new Staff { \clef bass \accLeft }
    >>
  >>
}
```

[image]

---

If this option fails, you can:

- fill in the `NullVoice` manually (Example A below),
- enter manual durations for your lyrics (this, however, gives a bad visual output) (Example B below), or
- keep all the music in one voice and all the rests in another one and keep switching using `\voiceOne` and `\voiceTwo` (Example C below).

**Example A**

```
\version "2.18.2"
\language "deutsch"

global = {
  \time 4/4
  \set Timing.beamExceptions = #'()
  \set Timing.baseMoment = #(ly:make-moment 1/8)
  \set Timing.beatStructure = #'(2 2 1 1 2)
}

melody = \relative d' {
  \global
   r4 r r8 d d d
}

accRight = \relative h {
  \global
  r8 <h d g> q q q r r4
}

accLeft = \relative g, {
  \global
  g4 g' g, g'
}

textRhythm = { r8 c c c c c c c }
alltextOne = \lyricmode { (a a a a) a a a }
alltextTwo = \lyricmode { (b b b b) b b b }

\score {
  <<
    \new ChoirStaff <<
      \new Staff <<
        \new Voice { \voiceOne \melody }
        \new Voice { \voiceTwo \accRight }
        \new NullVoice = "allvoice" { \textRhythm }
      >>
      \new Lyrics \lyricsto "allvoice" { \alltextOne }
      \new Lyrics \lyricsto "allvoice" { \alltextTwo }
      \new Staff { \clef bass \accLeft }
    >>
  >>
}
```

**Example B**

```
\version "2.18.2"
\language "deutsch"

global = {
  \time 4/4
  \set Timing.beamExceptions = #'()
  \set Timing.baseMoment = #(ly:make-moment 1/8)
  \set Timing.beatStructure = #'(2 2 1 1 2)
}

melody = \relative d' {
  \global
   r4 r r8 d d d
}

accRight = \relative h {
  \global
  r8 <h d g> q q q r r4
}

accLeft = \relative g, {
  \global
  g4 g' g, g'
}

alltextOne = \lyricmode { \skip8 (a8 a8 a8 a)8 a8 a8 a8 }
alltextTwo = \lyricmode { \skip8 (b8 b8 b8 b)8 b8 b8 b8 }

\score {
  <<
    \new ChoirStaff <<
      \new Staff <<
        \new Voice { \voiceOne \melody }
        \new Voice { \voiceTwo \accRight }
      >>
      \new Lyrics { \alltextOne }
      \new Lyrics { \alltextTwo }
      \new Staff { \clef bass \accLeft }
    >>
  >>
}
```

**Example C**

```
\version "2.18.2"
\language "deutsch"

global = {
  \time 4/4
  \set Timing.beamExceptions = #'()
  \set Timing.baseMoment = #(ly:make-moment 1/8)
  \set Timing.beatStructure = #'(2 2 1 1 2)
}

musicMusic = \relative d' {
  \global
  \voiceTwo r8 <h d g> q q q \voiceOne d d d
}

musicRests = {
    \global
    \voiceOne r4 r r8 \voiceTwo r8 r4
}

accLeft = \relative g, {
  \global
  g4 g' g, g'
}

alltextOne = \lyricmode { (a a a a) a a a }
alltextTwo = \lyricmode { (b b b b) b b b }

\score {
  <<
    \new ChoirStaff <<
      \new Staff <<
        \new Voice = "musicvoice" { \voiceOne \musicMusic }
        \new Voice = "restsvoice" { \voiceTwo \musicRests }
      >>
      \new Lyrics \lyricsto "musicvoice" { \alltextOne }
      \new Lyrics \lyricsto "musicvoice" { \alltextTwo }
      \new Staff { \clef bass \accLeft }
    >>
  >>
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It really helped. I have already used option B, which is for this piece fine, because almost everything is here in the length of quaver. But I like the other possibilities too. I will use them in another songs.

Answer (score 3):

This answer was a good answer, but I also found in the lilypond documentation that you can add markup to rests quite easily
http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/writing-rests

This is the particular snippet I found useful. (you don't have to compress the rests, the `\textLengthOn`  (then off) command will make the measure fit the preceding markup text.

```
\relative c' {
  \compressFullBarRests
  \textLengthOn
  ^\markup { [MAJOR GENERAL] }
  R1*19
  _\markup { \italic { Cue: ... it is yours } }
  ^\markup { A }
  R1*30^\markup { [MABEL] }
  \textLengthOff
  c4^\markup { CHORUS } d f c
}
```